# Geometric interpretation of $\binom{n+2}{3}$ in Knuth's book

Tags: binomial-coefficients

In Knuth's book "The art of computer programming" Vol 1, p.52, there is a picture with the caption "Geometric interpretation of $\binom{n+2}{3}$, $n=4$" (see attached photo).

[image: picture from Knuth's book]

I cannot figure out what it is. I did notice that there are $\binom{4+2}{3}=20$ dots and each dot is at the intersection of exactly 3 straight lines (and I don't know why some are dotted). Any suggestions?

Comment: DIdn't it occur to you to think why is it presented adjacent to a discussion about "Pascal's triangle"?

Comment: Yes it did, but at most the picture illustrates that a certain sum along a column of Pascal's triangle is equal to $\binom{n+2}{3}$ (and this formula is only discussed two pages later). The picture doesn't give a geometric interpretation of $\binom{n+2}{3}$ itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $n$th triangle number is the sum of the first $n$ positive integers. Therefore the $n$th triangle number is
$$ \sum_{k=1}^n k = \frac{n(n+1)}{2} = \binom{n+1}{2}. $$
See [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number) for more information on triangle numbers.

The $n$th tetrahedral number is the sum of the first $n$ triangular numbers. The picture in Knuth's book is of the $4$th tetrahedral number: notice how each layer represents a triangle number. The $n$th tetrahedral number is 
$$ \sum_{k=1}^n \binom{k+1}{2} = \binom{n+2}{3}. $$
See [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedral_number) for more information on tetrahedral numbers.

Comment: Yes, this is clearly what the picture refers to. But I am still unhappy with the caption. It should say "geometric interpretation of $\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{k+1}{2}=\binom{n+2}{3}, n=4$". That is what  the picture illustrates. To illustrate the binomial coefficient $\binom{4+2}{3}$ itself, I would look for its combinatorial meaning of choosing $3$ objects out of $4+2$ (and the reason for splitting $6$ into $4+2$ would still be unclear).  Also, the summation formula in question is only presented two pages later.

Answer (score 1):

There is a song called The Twelve Days of Christmas. If you go through it carefully, the total number of gifts accumulated at day number $n$ is your
 $$  \binom{n+2}{3} = \frac{(n+2)(n+1)n}{6}$$
In particular, at the end of the song, we have completed $n=12$ days, total gifts
$$ \frac{14 \cdot 13 \cdot 12}{6} = 364 $$

Wikipedia says it probably began as a memory game for children, each child would try to recite part of it...

> The exact origins and the meaning of the song are unknown, but it is
>   highly probable that it originated from a children's memory and
>   forfeit game.

[LYRICS](https://web.sonoma.edu/users/w/wilsonst/Courses/Math_300/Groupwork/Nos23-/GWSp34/GWSp34m1.html)

Comment: That is interesting. But I note that the book says "[binomial coefficients] appeared in Greek and Roman writings with a geometric interpretation (cf Fig. 8)" and Fig. 8 is the picture in question. Ancient Greek and Roman writers could not have the 12 days of Christmas in mind.

Comment: @Math101  If you are in the US, you ought to be able to find a pool table, with a rack. Fifteen balls go in the layer directly on the table. If you have a supply of extras, you can then pile an additional twenty on that, making a triangular pyramid of thirty five. Again, $7 \cdot 6 \cdot 5 / 6 = 35.$ At the same time, i have no real idea what you were asking.

Comment: Yes, if we sum the first $n$ triangular numbers $\binom{k+1}{2}$ we get $\binom{n+2}{3}$, and the picture in the book is a clear geometric illustration of that. But I was wondering why the author wrote that it is a geometric illustration of the binomial coefficient $\binom{n+2}{3}, n=4$. It is instead  a geometric illustration of the formula that you describe with the billiard balls, that is not done until two pages later in the book.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is called the Pascal Pyramid of monomials. It has a base of n = 4, and the 3 refers to the dimension. 
See this image of [Labeled Coefficents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPaHQ.png)
.  It counts the number of terms that are possible of a degree $\leq$ n-1.

There are 20 combinations of 3 variables that are of a degree $\leq 4-1$.